# Change Class with jquery

Tags: jquery, css

Hi i use a css framework from w3school.com so i need to change some class to get better view evry time the user change the window width, and for that i use jquery but doesn't work, can get help pleas and thank you
her is the code source.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://www.w3schools.com/lib/w3.css">
  <script http://googleads.g.doubleclick.net/pcs/click?xai=AKAOjsskoPaKjpYu8DK0oiP7OYYa9-A9I7CpjKFG67eM5bDqwk7ZV2TT-34qu4fCp92Y2TEIfbX8dj-6vPUezLZ60FPo9y2zGtNrl64NtBc_79RxtrJhBn26YWvvq1XiSZtWXfY-ML7nBmtrCTm02RWO8eiXGK-gctEOfZvzaFRQISYn4GlDgpkqNyEMUm6X6-eKP7xTMr4vzjmPShzKYVE_xNd-siI_3Pk_-2U6c3x5HZpHZGOg6Fo&sig=Cg0ArKJSzAR_3zib5yc4&adurl=http://www.w3schools.com/w3css/w3css_templates.asp&nm=2&nx=179&ny=48&mb=1src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
 var w = window.innerWidth;
 function resize(){
 if (w > 1366){
   $(".object").addClass("w3-quarter").removeClass("w3-half w3-third");
 } if else (w <= 1366 && w > 800){
   $(".object").addClass("w3-third").removeClass("w3-half w3-qurter");
 } else { $(".object").addClass("w3-half").removeClass("w3-third w3-qurter");
 }
 }
 $(document).ready(function(){
 resize();
 $(window).resize(resize);
 });

</script>
</head>
<body>

 <h1>Heading 1</h1>
 <h2>Heading 2</h2>

 <div class="object w3-qurter">
    <p>This is a paragraph.</p>
    <p>This is another paragraph.</p>
 </div>
 <div class="object w3-qurter">
    <p>This is a paragraph.</p>
    <p>This is another paragraph.</p>
  </div>
 <div class="object w3-qurter">
   <p>This is a paragraph.</p>
   <p>This is another paragraph.</p>
 </div>
 <div class="object w3-qurter">
   <p>This is a paragraph.</p>
   <p>This is another paragraph.</p>
 </div>


 </body>
 </html>
```

Comment: I would strongly suggest you dump the W3Schools library. Frankly, it's absolute garbage, along with most things W3S related. If you want a reliable, cross browser, responsive CSS framework, try Bootstrap instead.

Comment: thank you for you advice I'm beginner in coding i will do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
you have not called jquery properlly, please add jquery as mentioned in below code.

<html>
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://www.w3schools.com/lib/w3.css">
  <script src="http://googleads.g.doubleclick.net/pcs/click?xai=AKAOjsskoPaKjpYu8DK0oiP7OYYa9-A9I7CpjKFG67eM5bDqwk7ZV2TT-34qu4fCp92Y2TEIfbX8dj-6vPUezLZ60FPo9y2zGtNrl64NtBc_79RxtrJhBn26YWvvq1XiSZtWXfY-ML7nBmtrCTm02RWO8eiXGK-gctEOfZvzaFRQISYn4GlDgpkqNyEMUm6X6-eKP7xTMr4vzjmPShzKYVE_xNd-siI_3Pk_-2U6c3x5HZpHZGOg6Fo&sig=Cg0ArKJSzAR_3zib5yc4&adurl=http://www.w3schools.com/w3css/w3css_templates.asp&nm=2&nx=179&ny=48&mb=1" ></script>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
 var w = window.innerWidth;
 var w = window.innerWidth;
 function resize(){
 if (w > 1366){
   $(".object").addClass("w3-quarter").removeClass("w3-half w3-third");
 } else if (w <= 1366 && w > 800){
   $(".object").addClass("w3-third").removeClass("w3-half w3-qurter");
 } else { $(".object").addClass("w3-half").removeClass("w3-third w3-qurter");
 }
 }
 $(document).ready(function(){
 resize();
 $(window).resize(resize);
 });

</script>
</head>
<body>

 <h1>Heading 1</h1>
 <h2>Heading 2</h2>

 <div class="object w3-qurter">
    <p>This is a paragraph.</p>
    <p>This is another paragraph.</p>
 </div>
 <div class="object w3-qurter">
    <p>This is a paragraph.</p>
    <p>This is another paragraph.</p>
  </div>
 <div class="object w3-qurter">
   <p>This is a paragraph.</p>
   <p>This is another paragraph.</p>
 </div>
 <div class="object w3-qurter">
   <p>This is a paragraph.</p>
   <p>This is another paragraph.</p>
 </div>


 </body>
 </html>
```

Comment: OK i will do just can you verify my jquery code because i will use bootstrap framework and thank you.

Comment: Your jquery code is fine, you only need to add bootstrap class to manage the width of div having class name "object".

see the below code...

`function resize(){
 if (w > 1366){
   $(".object").addClass("col-lg-2").removeClass("col-sm-12 col-sm-3");
 } else if (w <= 1366 && w > 800){
   $(".object").addClass("col-sm-3").removeClass("col-sm-12 col-lg-2");
 } else { $(".object").addClass("col-sm-12").removeClass("col-lg-2 col-sm-3");
 }
 }`

Answer (score 0):

You are only getting the window.innerWidth on the first time the script loads. Move the variable w inside of the resize function so that you check each time the function is called:

```
  function resize(){
   //This will check width every time the resize function is called
   var w = window.innerWidth;
     if (w > 1366){
     $(".object").addClass("w3-quarter").removeClass("w3-half w3-third");
     } if else (w <= 1366 && w > 800){
     $(".object").addClass("w3-third").removeClass("w3-half w3-qurter");
     } else { $(".object").addClass("w3-half").removeClass("w3-third w3-qurter");
    }
   }
```

Comment: Thank you but it still does'nt work if you can tell a noder way to do that